# Excel: circle shape changes form in print preview.

Tags: excel, shapes

When you draw a perfect circle shape in Excel and you take it in print preview, you will notice that it isn't round anymore but it has flattened.
A friend of mine had this problem on his PC, but when I tried it on mine I get exactly the same result.
No idea why.
Can someone help? Adapting the margins and general properties doesn't work.

Comment: Switching to an application that is designed for drawing and printing perfect circles (like AutoCad for example) is not an option? I guess aspect ratio's of monitors and printers has something to do with this...

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately he needs it in Excel for work apparently. Any workaround possible you think?

Comment: Not that I know of. It is a very old problem :)

Comment: Ok let's leave it at an unsolved Microsoft bug then :-) I've lookup on many posts, but no real solution found...

Comment: There is 1 option though but that will spoil the image in the worksheet but you print preview will look good... A perfect circle will have the same width as the height. If you increase the height slightly then your print preview will look good and so will the print out... A crude solution I must say :(

Comment: Hehe, as in France they say: Chipotage? :-) Like stretching the image more in the other direction.

Comment: Quite creative, that is! :-) I will tell him to do that. Indeed, at least it will be a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the technicalities, the short answer is that since your monitor and your printer have very different resolutions (ie., [DPI/dots per inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) versus [PPI/pixels per inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)), plus the pixels/dots aren't even necessarily the same [shape](https://www.scantips.com/lights/resize2.html#aspect), so some manipulation is needed in order to get a printed shape identical to one you drew in Excel.

Below are some related links.  (Drawing a perfect square is obviously the same issue.)

- Microsoft Support: [**Column width is not the same when printed in Excel**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/214394/the-column-width-is-not-the-same-when-printed-in-excel)
- Digital Trends: [**Pixels, Printers, Video: What's With That?**](https://www.scantips.com/lights/pixels.html)
- Excel Forum: [**Drawing/printing an exact circle**](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/478575-drawing-printing-an-exact-circle.html)
- SuperUser: [**How to make cells perfect squares in Excel?**](https://superuser.com/q/165738/774713)
- Mr.Excel: [**Using Excel Worksheet as Gridpaper for Drawing**](https://www.mrexcel.com/tech-tv/excel-worksheet-as-gridpaper-for-drawing/)
- Stack Overflow: [**How to draw a circumference in a graph in Excel**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47448107/8112776)
- Digital Trends: [**Adjust high-DPI scaling in Windows 10**](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-adjust-high-dpi-scaling-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't technically a fix for the problem itself, but it's definitely the simplest workaround that doesn't involve guessing squished proportions to offset the flattening when printed.

Simply go to the "View" tab, and change the view from normal to "Page Layout" (you'll notice your image now looks distorted here just like it does on the print preview).

Now - just insert the image again while in THIS view, and you'll notice it's inserted with the correct proportions.

If you go back to the regular view, excel will have now squished it correctly so that the printing will appear as a perfect circle (or whatever proportionally important shape you're trying to print!)

Additional:
Since this bug is affected by the computer's DPI settings, and not the file itself, please note that if you're opening this workbook on multiple computers, they might all print out differently if excel changes the shape differently than on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround: Do a screenshot of the circle shape that you need to print from excel (Snipping Tool for example) then trim it and paste it. That will print right

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Excel that prevents the "text box" from being distorted in the printed version. I used it for pictures and circles as well and it works.

1. First, you have to make at least one "text box" on your page with some text in it.
2. Then you hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and select your text box plus all other pictures and objects on your page.
3. Right-click on one of the selected objects and in the pop-up dialog box select "Size and Properties".
4. In "Size and Properties" open "Text Box" and put checkmark on "Resize shape to fit text".