# How to draw a circumference in a graph in Excel (eventually with macro)

Tags: vba, excel, graph, excel-formula

I´d like to draw a circumference in a graph in Excel based on a radius value written in a cell.
I know how to draw Circle by macro but not in an Excel Graph.

Any help are welcome

Thx so much
M.

Comment: You can get a circle in a bubble graph, that might help

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to do some off to the side calculations. For example, with columns t, X, and Y:

- Your first point (x, y) will be any point on the circle with radius r.
- Your next point will use the math here https://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html based on the first point and whatever t you wish (smaller increments will produce a more accurate circle)
- Keep using that math until you hit 360 degrees.

Assuming r = 5, centered at (5, 10), and using t increments of 0.25:

[image]